# Apache Solr: undefined field "?publicationNumber"

Tags: csv, solr

I'm doing my first steps with solr and for that I try to load my own data from csv using a schema adapted from the example supplied. I replaced the fields with my own fields.

```
<field name="publicationNumber" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
```

Plus more fields. When I knwo try to load data using command from solr documentation:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update/csv?stream.file=exampledocs/test.csv^&stream.contentType=text/csv;charset=utf-8
```

(Windows hence the ^ before the &)

I get the error:

```
undefined field: "?publicationNumber"
```

The first column in csv is publicationNumber. However the field is clearly defined and what is it with the ? before the field name? How can I load the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always the same. You try for hours and as soon as you make a forum post you find the solution. Pretty simple. Even so the command says charset=utf-8 the csv file must not be in utf-8 encoding but ANSI. Eg. converting to ANSI and it worked without issue.